# CDN: Alternatives to SimpleCDN Mirror Bucket?

Tags: networking, cdn, content-delivery-network

I'm using http://SimpleCDN.com

They have a "Mirrored Bucket" which is an "origin pull".

How it works is I store my conent at mysite.com/abc.jpg and SimpleCDN pulls any requests from mysite.com, caches them in their CDN if not already in the cache, and display my content at simplecdn.com

I really like Origin Pull because I don't have to synch and/or FTP my content to their site, they simply pull it from my site (the origin) if it's not already in their cache.

However, recently, I've been having A LOT of problems with reliability and uptime of their service.

**Question**: Does anyone else know of a similarly priced CDN that offers "origin pull" CDN service that has great reliably and fast speeds at a reasonable price?

Answer (score 0):

We have been using http://www.istreamlive.net. We tried Simple CDN, but their service is just terrible.